# What is the best way of Polymer 0.9 "filters"?

Tags: polymer

In 0.5 it was possible to add a JS-functions like:

```
PolymerExpressions.prototype.timeofdate = function(input) {
 if(input) {
   return input.substring(11,16)
}
```

(Extracting hour:minute from "MongoDB-timestamp" like 2014-10-04T12:34:56+02:00)

And use it with piped variable like:

```
{{starts | timeofdate}}
```

When I tried to upgrade the code above to 0.9, I had to create this element instead:

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-substr',
    properties: {
      start: Number,
      end: Number,
    },
    attached: function() {
      this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.substring(this.start, this.end);
    }
  });
</script>
```

And use it like this:

```
<x-substr start="11" end="16">{{starts}}</x-substr>
```

(Use "attached" callback instead of "ready", if you should use this element with any data binding)

Is this the "right way" to do filter functionality like above in Polymer 0.9+?

Answer (score 1):

The closest you will get to the filter behaviour in 0.5 are [computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.9/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed) in 0.9+.

For your example this would be something like this:

```
<dom-module id="...">
  <template>
    ...
    <span>{{timeofdate(starts)}}</span>
    ...
   </template>
<dom-module>

Polymer({
  ...
  timeofdate: function (input) {
    return input.substring(11,16);
  }
  ...
});
```

If you need this time in more than one place you could also make it a [computed property](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.9/docs/devguide/properties.html#computed-properties) instead.

```
<dom-module id="...">
  <template>
    ...
    <span>{{starttime}}</span>
    ...
   </template>
<dom-module>

Polymer({
  ...
  properties: {
    starts: String,
    starttime: {
      type: String,
      computed: 'timeofdate(starts)'
    }
  },
  timeofdate: function (input) {
    return input.substring(11,16);
  }
  ...
});
```

Comment: I tried the way you suggested first, but I didn't got it to work inside of a "dom-repeat template" with data binding from a iron-ajax element with json data... Have you tested your approach inside of  a "dom-repeat template" with something like: `<your-element>{{item.orginalstring}}</your-element>`?

Comment: I now also got the "computed property way" to work, with an input string as a parameter like this: `<local-subst11to16 input={{item.jsonvalue}}></local-subst11to16>` (I don't really knew, what I did wrong earlier). Anyway using the attached callback in a small element (with only some JS) as a "filter" also works and there is maybe no "best way". Perhaps "PolymerExpressions.prototype" or similar showing up again in the future...